# What is the current status on css 3 and using prefix for rounded corners?

Tags: css

I used to do `-webkit-border-radius` and `-moz-border-radius` but now that there is ie9 I was wondering which prefix I should use. So after some googling I found this:

> When we added border-radius, we decided not to use –ms as the specification was a Candidate Recommendation at the time. The full module is again a Working Draft to resolve box-shadow issues but border-radius is still at Candidate Recommendation stability. Other browsers either already support the unprefixed version or will in an upcoming release.

[source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/11/15/ie9-vendor-prefixes-and-developers.aspx)

So I guess I should use:

```
-moz-border-radius
-webkit-border-radius
border-radius
```

It also seems that chrome supports a non-prefixed border-radius but Firefox doesn't so I was wondering if I should only use:

```
-moz-border-radius
border-radius
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is using the example below because altough newer browers dont require the prefix, older browsers that did require the prefix wont work without it

```
-moz-border-radius
-webkit-border-radius
border-radius
```